# Flutter error I/TextInputPlugin , W/IInputConnectionWrapper

Tags: flutter, dart

1

Error:

I/TextInputPlugin(22952): Composing region changed by the framework. Restarting the input method.

W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22952): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection

W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22952): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection

W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22952): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection

Is anyone how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

use a TextEditingController() to store the value in the textfield controller.
and then call the text value using theController.text .

this error is due to the keyboard being manually closed, it causes a rebuild.
make sure you're doing this in a stateful widget.
check this image for a guide.
[TextEditingController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38uc4.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).